# Testing Convergence of Integral

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

How do I prove that the integral: $\int_0^1 x^p{} (1-x)^q dx$  converges or diverges?

Comment: I fixed the formatting of the expression for you. Tip: Write your expressions like this: \$expression\$ to get them to parse in a line or use \$\$expression\$\$ to get them to parse at the center of a new line.

Answer (score 2):

Where do we have problems, and under what conditions they are vanished?

**Hint** :

Separate the integral into two integrals, one from $0$ to $1/2$ and the other from $1/2$ to $1$.

Then find for what values of $p$ and $q $ , both integrals converge.

Answer (score -2):

**HINT:**

The integrand is the kernel of a  Beta$(p+1,q+1)$ density, and so the integral converges if $p>-1, q>-1$.

In that case, the value is 
$$
  \int_0^1 x^p (1-x)^q dx
= B(p+1,q+1)
= \frac{\Gamma(p+1)\Gamma(q+1)}{\Gamma(p+q+2)},
$$
and in the case that $p$ and $q$ are integers, this is equal to $\frac{p!q!}{(p+q+1)!} = \frac{1}{\binom{p+q}{p}(p+q+1)}$